# "Wohlgetan" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from a monologue of a young woman about her strange love (it's a large part of a long, multilayered story, with a lot of archaisms).

> "Jetzt tändelt er mit mir und neckt und foppt mich, und ich weiß nicht, woran ich bin. Bin ich ihm lästig? Ein Kind, so **wohlgetan**? Sieht er nicht die Frau in mir? Was für ein Spiel treibt er nur?"

All the definitions of "wohlgetan" or "wohltun" I've been able to find (which isn't many) don't seem to fit. There hasn't been any interaction between them for the guy to praise her, and the other option seems to be that somebody there is feeling good, but I don't understand who... Another option I see is that it's to indicate a sort of condescending stance, that he treats her kindly but not seriously.

Edit: [Link to the author's page on Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Schacht)

The title of the book is: Das Spiel des Sängers

Comment: I understand this as "He treats me well, but like a kid" - But even for a native speaker the sense is hard to grasp.

Comment: same here, i was pretty good in school at interpreting stuff, but this is kinda hard... i think @tofro is right, that he is favorable towards her, but treats her like a child... maybe it could help, if you mentioned where this monologue is from and what the context of the situation is...

Comment: It's from a book that I doubt anyone else has read, since I didn't find any ratings or reviews on Amazon (it's called "Das Spiel des Sängers"), but the context is quite well described in the quote. The guy has just kissed the girl without permission and she was outraged, although she's in love with him, except they have a history that makes clear communication difficult... I don't know if I would consider that kiss a reward.

Comment: I get the impression that she repeats something that he had said about her.

Comment: And it's always possible that the author just got one of the archaisms wrong.

Comment: Who is the author, when was it written? Where does the author origin (DE, A, CH, ...?) Do you have a link?

Comment: [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Schacht) Everything's there.

Comment: I go with @Carsten S - This seems to be a mis-use of an archaism. *Wohlgetan* in a historic context would more or less translate to "well done" - Which doesn't make any sense to me here.

Comment: It seems that this is indeed a reference to an earlier use of the word in the story. That earlier use is in a song that begins with two lines from the Carmina Burana, the first is “Ich war ein Kind so wohlgetan” (or in the Carmina Burana “Ich was ein chint so wolgetan”). So the question remains what the word means there.

Comment: Well, damn, I thought I'd seen the expression previously, but Kindle refused to find it, and I wrote it off as dejavu... Anyway, those poems seem to be not even pretend-archaic, but simply really old, so I don't even hope to understand half of them. Fortunately they only precede the giant chapters in this book, so not much is lost, except in this unfortunate case... Kindle, you scoundrel! Found it. Anyway, in the poem I took it to mean something like "good-looking", or "well-raised"... or anything around there. Since it's about the seduction of the "Kind".

Comment: Btw, why are we doing this in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original meaning of “wohlgetan” is of course “done well”, but it also has taken the meaning of “beautiful” when applied to a person, [see DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GW25447). In this latter meaning the word is used earlier in the book in the line “Ich war ein Kind so wohlgetan” (taken from the Carmina Burana), apparently with some reference to the woman who is now unhappy about having been referred to as a child.

Comment: Holy molly, we're there finally, and immediately bookmarking that source! But to explain the situation more in detail, the guy previously sang this song about the seduction of a pretty young girl, and he's acting in a very womanizing manner, so the young woman later wonders whether he's in it just for a fling (or to take advantage of her like an innocent child) and quotes the line from the poem he'd sung... At least I reckon it's something like that.